# How can I pass value to a Specified parameter in stored procedure using my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, parameters

The following is my code

```
public static DataSet GetDataSet(string storedProcedure, params object[] parameters)
{
    ConnectionHelper c = new ConnectionHelper();
    c.opencon();
    c.getcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    c.getcmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
    c.getcmd.Parameters.Clear();

    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(c.getcmd);
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    foreach (SqlParameter SPParams in c.getcmd.Parameters)
    {
        if (j > 0)
        {
            SPParams.Value = parameters[i];
            i++;
        }
        j++;
    }

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = c.getcmd;
    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code? You are setting values to the parameters. Are you getting any error? What is the type of `prameters` variable?

Comment: I like to create a single stored procedure for select, edit, view and insert. But for select i use only two parameter ID and mode, mode for select and id for given id like 1001, but code pass values to stored procedure in an order. only first and second parameter catch the value not the specified one. (Sorry for my english..)

Comment: *I like to create a single stored procedure for select, edit, view and insert.* - really bad idea - read up on the **Single Responsibility Principle** - each piece of code should do **one thing** only - don't create "do-it-all" procedures, those are notoriously hard to write and a nightmare to maintain...

Comment: Hi, marc_s using this Single Responsibility Principle, number of stored procedure is increased. So that's why I try to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
public static DataSet GetDataSet(string storedProcedure, params object[] parameters)
```

Try passing parameters as a key value pair. Example:

```
public static DataSet GetDataSet(string storedProcedure, params KeyValuePair<string, object> parameters)
```

`string` will store the name of the parameter and `object` will hold the value.
This way you can pass value by named parameters. Only these parameter's value will be set and rest will remain null (order doesn't matter)

Usage:

```
foreach (var param in parameters)
{
   c.getcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(param.Key, param.Value));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, but it get an error like  "The parameter array must be a single dimensional array " int params of public static DataSet GetDataSet(string storedProcedure, params KeyValuePair<string, object> prameters)

Comment: are you using it like GetDataSet("spName", new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ParamName", objValue) ?

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are looking for something like this. Here one stored procedure with all insert update delete select together. @QueryType must to pass all every single time, however the rest variable need to call only when needed because it assignd default values respectively if no value is passed.

Example >> MyTable has 3 fields, ID (int PK autoincrease, Field1 int, Field2 varchar(20), Below is single stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInserUpdateDeleteSelect 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @QueryType varchar(10),
    @ID int = 0,
    @Field1 int = 0,
    @Field2 varchar(20) = NULL

BEGIN
        IF @QueryType = 'INSERT' BEGIN
            INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES (@Field1, @Field2)
        END

        ELSE IF @QueryType = 'UPDATE' BEGIN
            UPDATE MyTable 
            SET Field1 = @Field1, Field2 = @Field2
            WHERE ID=@ID
        END

        ELSE IF @QueryType = 'DELETE' BEGIN
            DELETE FROM MyTable
            WHERE ID=@ID
        END

        ELSE IF @QueryType = 'SELECTALL' BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM MyTable
        END

        ELSE IF @QueryType = 'SELECTBYID' BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID=@ID  
        END

END


//For params Error, create a new class and pass as list of the class

    public class ParaNameValue
    {
        public string ParaName{ get; set; }
        public string ParaValue{ get; set; }

        public ParaNameValue(string PName, string PValue){
            this.ParaName=PName;
            this.ParaValue = PValue;
        }
    }

//For caller function, how to pass parameter list

    List<ParaNameValue> ListPara= new List<ParaNameValue>();
    ListPara.Add(new ParaNameValue("@Name", "BlaBla 1");
    ListPara.Add(new ParaNameValue("@Email", "BlaBla 2");

    GetDataSet(string storedProcedure, ListPara);


//for dataset function
    public static DataSet GetDataSet(string storedProcedure, List<ParaNameValue> ParaList)"
    {
        //do other stuffs here

        //getting sqlpara values
        foreach (ParaNameValue p in ParaList)
        {
             c.getcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(p.ParaName, p.ParaValue));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please mark as answer, it answers you. Please let me know if anything I can help.

Comment: still error in "params KeyValuePair<string, object> prameters" error said The parameter array must be a single dimensional array

Comment: this is my code used to pass value  public static DataSet ViewCandidate(ENT_CandidateRegister reg)
        {
            SqlParameter[] arParams = new SqlParameter[2];

            arParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@MODE", "view");
            arParams[1] = new SqlParameter("@EMAIL", reg.Email);
         

            DataSet ds = DataManager.GetDataSet("USP_REG", arParams);
            return ds;
        }

Comment: sParams[0] = new SqlParameter();
sParams[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
sParams[0].ParameterName = "@MODE";
sParams[0].Value = "view";

sParams[1] = new SqlParameter();
sParams[1].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
sParams[1].ParameterName = "@EMAIL";
sParams[1].Value = reg.Email;

Comment: error in "public static DataSet GetDataSet(string storedProcedure, params KeyValuePair<string, object> parameters)" parameter array must be single dimensional array!!

Comment: I believe you are passing key pair values with unwell-formed format.

Comment: My code at first like this  1st method used to add and 2nd one for select  public static void AddCandidate(ENT_CandidateRegister reg)
        {
            DataManager.InsertUpdateDelete("USP_REG", reg.Mode, reg.UserName, reg.FName, reg.MName, reg.LName, reg.Gender, reg.Email, reg.Mobile, reg.Resume, reg.Status, reg.Password, reg.Userid, reg.Location, reg.CreatedDate);
        }

        public static DataSet ViewCandidate(ENT_CandidateRegister reg)
        {
           
            DataSet ds = DataManager.GetDataSet("USP_REG", reg.Email,reg.Mode);
            return ds;
        }

Comment: No, I change my code like u said, but params error still occured.

Comment: Not using params anymore, still happening with params?

Comment: You mean like this " public static DataSet GetDataSet(string storedProcedure, KeyValuePair<string, object> prameters)"

Comment: No, don't use KeyValuePair anymore.

Comment: Can you send the code, i don't get what you said :(

Comment: this one? sParams[0] = new SqlParameter(); sParams[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int; sParams[0].ParameterName = "@MODE"; sParams[0].Value = "view"; sParams[1] = new SqlParameter(); sParams[1].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar; sParams[1].ParameterName = "@EMAIL"; sParams[1].Value = reg.Email;

Comment: No. Main answer. Below the stored procedure.

Comment: So, every table must create constructor? I want to use every select or update for this method. can i send my code to you by mail?